# Change Visibility of one Control when it is changed on another one

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, visibility, datatrigger

I got 3 Controls in my `XAML`.

If the `Visibility` from one of them changes to `Visible`, the others `Visibility` should change to `Hidden`. So that only one of them can be `Visible` at a time.

---

**My Xaml**

```
<Control x:Name="Unselected">
     <Control.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Control">
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Selection, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                 </DataTrigger>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Selected, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </Control.Style>
</Control>

<Control x:Name="Selection" Visibility="Hidden">
     <Control.Style>
          <Style TargetType="Control">
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Unselected, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                 </DataTrigger>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Selected, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                     </DataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
     </Control.Style>
</Control>

<Control x:Name="Selected" Visibility="Hidden">
     <Control.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Control">
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Selection, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                 </DataTrigger>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Unselected, Path=Visibility}" Value="Visible">
                     <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                 </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </Control.Style>
</Control>
```

Comment: How are you changing the visibility of the one you want to show?

Comment: @KyleHancock From Code-behind

Comment: You want to show just one control at time... so what is your problem?

Comment: @IlVic That it does not work...

Comment: Why are you using three `Control`s? `Control` class is invisible...

Comment: @IlVic I am not really using `Control`s

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 `RadioButton` and modify their `Template` and use their `IsChecked` property. Only one of them would be checked at a time. Bind your `Visibility` property to `IsChecked` property. If `IsChecked` is true, `Visibility = Visible` else  `Visibility = Hidden` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use Binding and PropertyChanged. Setting the property will raise PropertyChanged and Triggers will execute.

XAML:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="false">
            <TextBox x:Name="Unselected" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Unselected">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumOptions}" Value="Unselected">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumOptions}" Value="Selection">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumOptions}" Value="Selected">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>

            <TextBox x:Name="Selection" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Selection">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumOptions}" Value="Unselected">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumOptions}" Value="Selection">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumOptions}" Value="Selected">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>

            <TextBox x:Name="Selected" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="Selected">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumOptions}" Value="Unselected">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumOptions}" Value="Selection">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumOptions}" Value="Selected">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>

            <Button Content="Unselected" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
            <Button Content="Selection" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Button_Click_1"></Button>
            <Button Content="Selected" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="Button_Click_2"></Button>
        </DockPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EnumOptions = Options.Unselected;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EnumOptions = Options.Selection;
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EnumOptions = Options.Selected;
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private Options _enumOptions;
    public Options EnumOptions
    {
        get { return _enumOptions; }
        set
        {
            _enumOptions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EnumOptions");
        }
    }
}

public enum Options
{
    Unselected,
    Selection,
    Selected
}
```

Basically, you will set need to set property like this

```
EnumOptions = Options.Unselected;
```

instead of

```
Unselected.Visibility = true;
```